# Silverlight: Why can't designer see the dependency property?

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties

I have to create Silverlight User Control with public properties that should be used in inner controls.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl 
{

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MyCustom", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), 
                 new PropertyMetadata("defaultValue"));

  public string MyCustom
  {
              ... 
}
```

I tried several ways to bind, but all fail - dependency property is not seen for some reason.
For example this straightforward binding fails:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...MyControl"
    ...
    x:Name="mc"
>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=MyCustom, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=mc}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing binding errors in the Output window? Chances are your string needs to be converted to an ImageSource like Anthony mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not a good pattern.  The UserControl does not really "own" the name property.  If another UserControl or Page were to place an instanced of your `MyControl` in its Xaml, it can give it name other than "mc", at which point your code is broken.

Instead use this approach:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="...MyControl"
>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Parent.MyCustom, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

That out of the way you main problem is that the `Image` `Source` property is of type `ImageSource` not string.  You get to use a string literal in Xaml because the Xaml parser does some parser magic the converts the string to an `ImageSource`.  This doesn't happen when using binding.

Change you controls property to:-

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl 
{

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MyCustom", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyControl), 
                 new PropertyMetadata(null));

  [TypeConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
  public ImageSource MyCustom
  {
              ... 
  }
```

Now in another UserControl or Page where you `MyControl` is hosted you can use a string to assign this `MyCustom` property.  However in code you need to create an instance of something like `BitmapImage` to assign to this property.

Comment: The naming issue was fixed in Silverlight 4. See this [blog post](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2009/11/19/silverlight-3-elementname-databinding-problem/). Also, isn't the Parent of the Image control the Grid?

Comment: @CodeNaked: Good spot this naming issue does indeed appear to sorted in SL4.  I still think its not a good idea to assign a name on the user control though, how many other controls are out there that have a "default" value to name.  As to the `Parent`, its not referencing the parent of the image control, the ElementName is pointing at the LayoutRoot.  So `Parent` points to the parent of the LayoutRoot which is the user control.

Comment: Ah, missed the ElementName part there :-)